# Como usar as propriedades de um elemento pai no CSS do filho?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma `<div>` com valores fixos, e ela possui uma `<ul>` internamente, como mostrado abaixo:

```
<div id="personalizado">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item_extremamente_longo_que_força_o_elementoa_vazar_para_fora_da_pagina</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

div#personalizado{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

ul{
  /*inserir aqui o estilo*/
}
```

Porém eu quero que o `<ul>` ou qualquer outra tag que eu inserir depois não "vaze" para fora, definindo o tamanho máximo ou o mínimo do elemento filho de acordo com as propriedades do elemento pai. Como eu posso fazer isso?

O que eu imagino seria algo parecido com isso:

```
#filho{
    max-width: #pai:width;
}
```

Comment: E como gostaria de exibir esse conteúdo? O que deve acontecer com o conteúdo que excede a largura do elemento pai?

Comment: Cara é só vc colocar max-width: 100% nos filhos diretos, mas sua pergunta é maio sem contexto, pq o filho do filho pode sair do avó, se o neto tiver um valor fixo em px por exemplo ele pode vazar o avó, não ficou muito claro, seria melhor vc explicar a situação, pois nem sempre uma resposta vai funcionar para todos os casos....

Comment: @hugocsl era mais a título de curiosidade mesmo, eu via lugares onde eu usava as mesmas propriedades do elemento pai (ou baseadas nele) e pensei que talvez fosse interessante usar direto os atributos do pai ao invés de setar eles manualmente

Comment: não seu preocupe com isso, trate cada casou, ou as coisas podem facilmente fugir do controle no seu layout... opinião pessoal minha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a propriedade `inherit` com ela você herda o valor da tag pai:

```
#filho{
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

Assim ele ira pegar o `max-width` da tag pai.

OBS: como a propriedade herda o valor da tag pai, então logo você tem que setar um valor de `max-width` na tag pai, senão não ira funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar 2 seletores, o > e o * e fazer assim:

```css
.pai > * {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
<span>Eu não estu dentro da li</span>
<ul>
  <li>Eu estou dentro da li</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

O asterísco tem como alvo todos os elementos, o > (maior) tem como característica os filhos de um elemento, ou seja, se você utilizar os 2, você estará pegando todos os filhos diretos do elemento selecionado. (diretos porque se for um elemento neto, ele não vai pegar)

Se quiser pegar todos os elementos mesmo dentro de **.pai** você poder usar `.pai * {}`